# How to restart for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

This might not be possible but if it is, I want to know how can it be done?

Here is my code-structure

```py
for item in somelist:
    # Calcuating some stuff
```

inside my for loop, I have some evaluation to do which might cause exception.
and even if I handle the exception, current iteration is passed as in complete
What I want to do is, if I get exception, I want to re-evaluate current iteration with some new information.
Is it possible?
Example

```py
for item in somelist:
    try:
        # calculating item
    except Exception:
        # re-running current iteration (not from the beginning)
```

Comment: Might want to take care - if re-evaluation results in another exception ... and so on ... you could end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Not possible. The `for` loop uses the iterator protocol, which means the only thing it can do (after using `iter(somelist)` to get the iterator in the first place) is call `next` on that iterator.

Comment: What you *can* do is put another loop in the body of the `for` loop which doesn't exit until you are finally done with `item` and ready to get the next value.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using an inner loop to handle the retry:

```
for item in somelist:
    while True:
        try:
            # calculating item
            break  # breaks inner loop, outer loop continues
        except Exception:
            # get new information, inner loop continues implicitly
```

If you want to retry a limited number of times to avoid the possibility of an infinite loop, that's easily accomplished by making the inner loop something like `for _ in range(NUM_RETRIES)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a list try using while instead of for loop

```py
i = 0
while i < len(somelist):
  item = somelist[i]
  try:
        # calculating item
  except Exception:
    i -= 1
  i += 1
```